# How is mode passed through Mage::app()->cleanCache($tags)?

Tags: configuration, cache

I'm trying to understand the behaviour of the `cleanCache()` method on `Mage_Core_Model_App`.

My understanding is of the sequence after `Mage::app()->cleanCache($tags)` is:

1. `Mage_Core_Model_App` will call `clean()` on its `_cache` attribute, which is `Zend_Cache_Core`. It doesn't pass a `$mode` parameter.
2. The signature for that method on cache core is `clean($mode = 'all', $tags = array())`. So only passing `$tags` should result in the default mode of 'all'.

However, when I debug, the `$mode` parameter in `Zend_Cache_Core::clean()` has a value of 'matchingAnyTag'.

If it's not passed in and the default isn't that, where does it get that value from? I think I must be missing something in the call chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_cache` attribute in `Mage_Core_Model_App` is an instance of `Mage_Core_Model_Cache`.
If you look at `Mage_Core_Model_Cache::clean()` you will see that the first line specifies the `$mode = Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG;`

```
public function clean($tags=array())
{
    $mode = Zend_Cache::CLEANING_MODE_MATCHING_ANY_TAG;
    if (!empty($tags)) {
        if (!is_array($tags)) {
            $tags = array($tags);
        }
        $res = $this->getFrontend()->clean($mode, $this->_tags($tags));
    } else {
        $res = $this->getFrontend()->clean($mode, array(Mage_Core_Model_App::CACHE_TAG));
        $res = $res && $this->getFrontend()->clean($mode, array(Mage_Core_Model_Config::CACHE_TAG));
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: Hmm I must have a different version. I don't see it set to that in the function, but set to 'all' as a default argument. I'll look to see if this class has been rewritten in my Magento autoload.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at `Zend_Cache_Core` when I should have been looking at `Mage_Core_Model_Cache`.